# Use User Parameters inside AbstractJavaSamplerClient

Tags: java, jmeter

I'm implementing a custom Java Request for Jmeter extending `AbstractJavaSamplerClient`.

Inside my class, I need to access an `User Parameters` pre-procesor that is defined in the Jmeter jmx file.  I have inspected the objetct `JavaSamplerContext` and I haven't found what I need.  How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User parameters saves values in JMeter variables, you can get them using [JMeterContext](https://gist.github.com/sanketdc/11261844)

> ```
> JMeterContext jMeterContext = getThreadContext();
> JMeterVariables variables = jMeterContext.getVariables();
> ```

Get specific variable

```
variables.get("varName")
```